# Multiselect list items overwrites instead of adding

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm trying to add multi-selected items to list  `_AT.SOrderDetails = new List<SOrderDetail>();` but the list is overwritten by the last record selected. The list at right Datagrid only shows data of the last selected record of the left Datagrid instead of all records

```
foreach (int i in ((GridView)gridControl3.MainView).GetSelectedRows())
        {

            DataRowView oSOrder = (DataRowView)((GridView)gridControl3.MainView).GetRow(i);

            int id = Convert.ToInt32(oSOrder.Row.ItemArray[0]);
            if (oSOrder == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("select an item to edit", "Item not yet selected", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                return;
            }
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(oSOrder["SOrderID"]);
            _Order = db.SOrderTables.FirstOrDefault(o => o.QSOrdersID == x);
            SOrderTable oOrder = null;
            oOrder = _Order;
            if (_Order != null)
            {
                _AT.SOrderDetails = new List<SOrderDetail>();
                if (_Order.SOrderDetails != null)
                {
                  

                    foreach (SOrderDetail oPODItem in _Order.SOrderDetails.ToList())
                    {
                        _OrderDetail = new SOrderDetail();
                        Product oProduct = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ProductID == oPODItem.ProductID);
                        _OrderDetail.ProductID = oPODItem.ProductID;
                        _OrderDetail.Description = oProduct.Description;
                        _OrderDetail.Quantity = oPODItem.Quantity;
                        _OrderDetail.Form = oPODItem.Form;
                        _OrderDetail.Price = oPODItem.Price;

                        _AT.SOrderDetails.Add(_OrderDetail);
                    }

                }

            }
           
        }
```

[The list at right Datagrid only shows data of the last selected record of the left datagrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLbk6.png)

How do I add all values of the selected records, I need help I'm still new, thank you.

Comment: I can't make sense of your image - you say that the right list shows only one selected item from the left list, but it shows 3 items and nothing in the right list is anything in common with the left list

Comment: hello, when the left list record is expanded it shows items that are on the right list, I got the solution, i was using the same list so it was overriding data when I created a new list everything is working correctly. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i created a new list  `_tapiwa.SOrderDetails = new List<SOrderDetail>();` So i was now saving information from list  `_Order.SOrderDetails.ToList();` to the new list i created.

```
 `foreach (int i in ((GridView)gridControl3.MainView).GetSelectedRows())
        {


            DataRowView oSOrder = (DataRowView)((GridView)gridControl3.MainView).GetRow(i);

            int id = Convert.ToInt32(oSOrder.Row.ItemArray[0]);

            if (oSOrder == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("select an item to edit", "Item not yet selected", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                return;
            }

            int x = Convert.ToInt32(oSOrder["SOrderID"]);
            _Order = db.SOrderTables.FirstOrDefault(o => o.QSOrdersID == x);

            label1.Text += (oSOrder.Row.ItemArray[0]).ToString()+"             "+ (oSOrder.Row.ItemArray[1]).ToString()+"               " + (oSOrder.Row.ItemArray[2]).ToString()+ "\n";

            SOrderTable oOrder = null;
            //  db = new MedriveEntities();
            oOrder = _Order;
         
            if (_Order != null)
            {
                if (_tapiwa == null)
                {
                    _tapiwa = new SOrderTable();
                    _tapiwa.SOrderDetails = new List<SOrderDetail>();
                }

                foreach (SOrderDetail oPODItem in oOrder.SOrderDetails.ToList())
                {


                    _OrderDetail = new SOrderDetail();

                   // label2.Text += oPODItem.ProductID.ToString() + "             " + oPODItem.Description.ToString() + "               " + oPODItem.Quantity.ToString() + "\n";
                        Product oProduct = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ProductID == oPODItem.ProductID);

                      _OrderDetail.ProductID = oPODItem.ProductID;
                      _OrderDetail.Description = oProduct.Description;
                      _OrderDetail.Quantity = oPODItem.Quantity;
                      _OrderDetail.Form = oPODItem.Form;
                       _OrderDetail.Price = oPODItem.Price;
                     _tapiwa.SOrderDetails.Add(_OrderDetail);
                    
                }



            }
            

        }
        RefreshList1();`
```